# Return AJAX images but jQuery click doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 7 images in my index HTML, and then I use a jQuery function, when I click the images the function gives me images' ids.

The function looks like:

```js
$(".imgss").click(function() {

  alert($(this).attr("id"));

});
```

`.imgss` is a class that iIgive, but I select another city in my select box and I send variable to PHP and AJAX gives me result of other new images.

When the new image is downloaded, I try to click the images but jQuery doesn't work.

New images also have `.imgss` class.

This is my php code to create images :

```php
print_r ("<div class='responsive' id='salonlarimi_goster'> 
<img src='$salonlarimi_ver[f1]' alt='salon_foto_5' width='250' height='250' 
id='$salonlarimi_ver[klavuz]' class='gelenimg'> 
<div class='desc'>$salonlarimi_ver[salon_isim]</div> </div>");
```

Comment: Try using `$(".imgss").on('click', function() { ... });` as your event handler

Comment: Can you share the code for refreshing the images after making a selection on city select box. It could be an issue with your image ids not getting registered to DOm after the ajax refresh.

Comment: hi, i tagged php code because i used php to take new images in another php file, i thought maybe it is relevant to this situation.  and i use this code to new images print_r ("<div class='responsive' id='salonlarimi_goster'>
        
       <img src='$salonlarimi_ver[f1]' alt='salon_foto_5' width='250' height='250' id='$salonlarimi_ver[klavuz]' class='gelenimg'>
     
     <div class='desc'>$salonlarimi_ver[salon_isim]</div>
      
    </div>");
  
 }

Comment: it could have relevance, we don't know that. You have that code and you should also include the HTML for all this, but if you feel you don't have to, then see the answers below and accept the best one you think solved the question then @Ömürcan and please don't drop code in comments, edit your question instead https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44780666/edit

Comment: sorry for some troubles, i am new in computer world, i try to learn the rules, thanks for your patience Fred

Answer (score 1):

I think you are working with dynamic html content, so instead of:

```
$(".imgss").click(function() {   // This works for static html
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

try

```
$(document).on('click', '.imgss', function() {   // This works for static as well as dynamic html
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

**Explanation:** The html which are loaded by `ajax()` are dynamic. To deal with that you have to use appropriate event listener.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, I dont know it before, but i have tried this code but it doesn't work, may i ask any other problem when i was using your code

Comment: i solved it works , thanx alot

Answer (score 1):

try this code. because when you download new image than jquery dont know about it.

```
$(document).on("click",".imgss",function() {
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: i tried it but situation is the same as old. it still works in first photos but new photos which ajax get, doesn't work

Comment: @Ömürcan Can you please share your whole code?

Comment: i solved it works , thanx alot Nirav.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.imgss').on('click', function() { 
  alert();
});
```

Comment: this code is working, thanx a lot Reena